# Why would a 9% dividend payment halve the stock price?

Tags: equities, dividends

I am trying to understand why a stock experienced a very drastic drop in price. The only event linked to the drop seems to be payment of an unusually big dividend; however its effect on the price seems too strong to fully explain it.

The company is in good shape and has a good quick ratio; the assets are much higher than the dividend.

Comment: If the company transfers a huge amount of their cash to their stock-holders, why would you expect the company value not to change?

Comment: Indeed, if the stock value wouldn't decrease value would be created out of nowhere.

Comment: The dividend is 9%, the stock price dropped by more than a half, cash flow wise this (to me) seems unusual.

Comment: 9% of what? Can you give us the name of the stock? Without more information the drop in market cap should be equal to the amount of dividends.

Comment: @BobJansen I find this an interesting question, it seems basic but I would rather say it is an empirical question to be investigated.

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger The dividend itself may be just 9%, but markets do not look at this one dividend but the entire expected future dividend stream. So the net present value effect of cutting all future dividend expectations might be much higher (50%) than the single dividend (9%) itself. E.g., after paying 10 times 9% of the stockprice in future, the stockprice would go close to 0.

Comment: @emcor I agree that it could be an interesting empirical question if the question is not just "why do dividends decrease stock price" and I'm happy to reopen. In that case, we _need_ more info because if you want take the empirical approach it is almost unanswerable in the current form.

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger Please tell us which stock it was, or the company profile? (moderator will reopen your question then)

Comment: It's probably the other way around. The stock was yielding 4.5% before, say a $4.50 dividend on a $100 stock price. Some piece of bad news (probably calling in question the safety of earnings and/or the dividend cut the price of the stock in half, so it is now yielding 9$, e.g. $4.50/$50.